# Society economy or society's economy?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am not sure about using this phrase **"society economy"** or **"society's economy"** to imply that the society provides the economy activities; the economy has been done by society.

- Biofuel energy is a new challenge with great values for agricultural commodity in increasing **society’s** ***economy/society economy***, particularly in rural areas.

Comment: Could you post some context -- a complete sentence, or maybe even more than that, where you want to insert this phrase?

Comment: @ruakh please see my edited phrase.

Comment: Hmm. There are actually quite a few problems with that sentence -- "with great values"? "For agricultural commodity"? "Increasing [modifier] economy"? You would probably be best off hiring a native speaker to translate this text for you. :-/

Comment: @ruakh: that's not an answer i am expecting :) anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

... in *improving the state of* the economy, particularly in rural areas.

You can't increase the economy. And, the word "economy" is normally used to describe the degree of economic trouble within a city, county, or state; that it concerns everyone in a given society is kind of implied. "Society's" sounds kind of silly.